# Why does comparing integers with Equal(=) takes 800ms more that using GreaterThan(>) and LessThan(<)

Tags: sql, .net, linq

Using Linq and EntityFramework we recently noticed, while testing our queries performances, that the use of Equal(=) operator to compare two integers takes around 800ms more than using a combination of GreaterThan(>) and LessThan(<) operators.

So basically, replacing `itemID == paramID` (Both being integers) by `!(itemID > param ID || itemID < paramID)` in our linq query makes the query faster by about 800ms consistently.

Anyone with a deep knowledge of SQL could explain this result to me?

Comment: `itemID = paramID` is assigning a value to `itemID` and not a comparrision. Is this a typo?. Also `=` isn't the operator for checking equality. `==` is.

Comment: Sorry yeah the single = was a typo. the linq statement uses == but it will result in a single = in the SQL statement that is executed on the server.

Comment: What indexes do you have on related database tables?

Comment: Without seeing the queries EF produces and the execution plans this gives, this question can't be answered. Incidentally, the SQL Server optimizer *is* capable of rewriting `NOT (A > X OR A < X)` into `A = X` for simple scalar `X`, and it can also rewrite to `A <= X AND A >= X`. But that's without even considering what query EF actually produces!

Comment: Use ObjectQuery.ToTraceString to get the SQL, paste it into SSMS, and view the query plans.   EF LINQ is the not the most performant want to way to get data from SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was always faster SQL Server would do the rewrite for you. It does not so you can conclude that it is *not* always faster to do this. In fact it is a bad idea to do this rewrite in 99.999% of the cases.

The information given in the question (almost none) does not allow for further analysis.

Often people ask "why did this random change make my query faster". The answer is always: You accidentally triggered a better query plan. There is no system to it.  Query plans can be unstable.

Psychic guess: The complex predicate forces a table scan (or makes it appear better) than using an index. That can sometimes be a good thing.

Comment: "You accidentally triggered a better query plan. There is no system to it. Query plans can be unstable."

Sorry I didn't want to put the whole query in the question, but anyway this already give me a better understanding of what is happening and what to look for. As you say, in 99% of the cases this rewrite wouldn't be a good idea as Equal is supposed to perform better, but I was wondering why in our query this wasn't the case.

Comment: Related to the Psychic guess: For _small_ datasets, the table scan is often faster than messing around with indices.  This will not scale well.

Comment: @Alex if you want more info ask a new question with the LINQ query, the generated SQL and the execution plan.

Comment: @usr I'll have a look at the actual execution plan and post a new question with everything if I don't find the explanation. Thanks for pointing me to the right places.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to examine the generated sql. My guess is `itemID` is `nullable` and EntityFramework's default behaviour with nullable properties isn't the greatest. It will translate your query into something like: `prop = value OR prop is null`

If that is the case and you are using EF6, you can overide that behaviour by:

```
context.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

[Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: I'll have a look into this as well, thanks a lot!